# how to add modules in pom.xml without a sequence

Tags: java, maven, module, version, pom.xml

I've an interview question regarding maven. If i've multiple modules in my project, how can i add them in the pom.xml witout following sequence. If the number of modules are less we can add them as required or as dependent, but the number is huge following a sequence is very difficult. Also how to add the version number dynamically? We can hard code the version number in the pom.xml but if it is modifying frequently how to add that dynamically?

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: "without following sequence" :  can you explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Maven has a reactor mechanism which will automatically sort your modules . The reactor sorts all the projects in a way that guarantees any project is built before it is required

checkout this link :
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html

2) Automatic version number will be easy to have if you are using a build tool like jenkins .

check out this link
https://dzone.com/articles/continuous-releasing-maven

Hope this helps